# How to loop through a nested loop and enumerate

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I am having a problem with my nested loops. I am getting an output, but it is duplicating each output for the number of fields in my data set.

```
for dat in data_body:
    x = float(dat[5])
    y = float(dat[6])
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(x,y)
    feature.SetGeometry(point)
    for i, d in enumerate(dat):
        for j, field in enumerate(new_fields):
            if i == j:
                feature.SetField(field, d)
                layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

For my datasets, the list of lists `data_body` has 13 rows of data and 55 columns (i.e. 55 positions). For my list `new_fields` I have a 55 values, which correspond to the columns of `data_body` list of lists. Thus, in my code block for the object `feature.SetField(field, d)`. I should have each value of the data_body correspond to each unique field, as long as rows match each other, i.e. `i` and `j`. However, rather getting an object back with 13 rows of data corresponding with column values corresponding to the values in `new_fields`. I get 13 * 55 values, i.e. 715 rows, where values are missing for ~ 50% of the data. My output data table kind of looks like a triangle of data.

I am not sure if my question makes sense, but if it does, any help with my nested looping strategies would be helpful. i think my issue is my conceptualization of what my loop is actually doing, as well as what my `if` statement might be doing.

Comment: you should iterate over `enumerate(dat)` and `enumerate(new_fields)` at the same time, rather then one inside other...

Comment: @avasal, thanks for the tip. But, how would I do that, simultaneously?

Comment: @avasal, I used the `zip` function, but I am still getting the same output. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer makes sense for what you're trying to do, because I'm not entirely sure what your objects are or what you mean by rows and columns.  Feel free to edit your question if I'm not understanding and comment on my response if I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As avasal said, you want to iterate over dat and new_fields at the same time, and the easiest way to do this is to use `zip`:

```
for d, field in zip(dat, new_fields):
    feature.SetField(field, d)
    layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

Comment: thank you @acjohnson55. I did do that, but unfortunately, i'm still getting the same output. as earlier with the nested loop. I will continue investigating why this may be happening. But thanks for the zip function explanation! And I will edit my code to hopefully relay my question better.

Comment: I think what might be happening now, is that first portion of the loop for `dat` in `data_body`, associates `x` and `y` (values in the list `new_fields`) with positions 5 and 6 in `dat`, which are rows in `data_body`. Perhaps, I don't even need the second loop, and just need to figure out a way to loop through both `new_fields` and `data_body` once and associated each value of `dat` with its respective position of `new_fields`. FYI: (`len(new_fields)` = 55)  and (`len(data_body)` = 13), with each row of `data_body` = `len` of 55)

Comment: What does SetField expect?  Are you trying to assign the same `new_fields` values to every item in `dat_body`?  Maybe what you want is to iterate only over `dat`, and then do `feature.SetField(new_fields, d)`